# Rails – different output in console and web

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following construct in some model

```
...
def somefield=(somefield)
  write_attribute(:somefield, Base64.encode64(somefield))
end
def somefield
  Base64.decode64(read_attribute(:somefield))
end
...
```

which works fine in rails console:

```
m = model.first
=> ...
m.somefield
=> "This is a base64 encoded string"
```

but when i use the same method in the rails server i'll get

```
VGhpcyBpcyBhIGJhc2U1NCBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
```

the base64 encoded string.
I wrapped the expression in the view with:

```
= Base64.decode64(data_row[:somefield])
```

This works fine, but it's not the rails way and a unfortunate solution.

Can someone tell why i get different output on console and on server and
how i can solve the problem with two different outputs?

(Using Rails 4.0.1, ruby 1.9.3p383)

Comment: I tried your code, worked great for me on the server.  Is there a chance this field is modified anywhere before this?  Maybe by a gem?  What is the field that is being encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'.send' is a solution for my problem.

```
m.send(somefield)
```

With send the procedure will run through the custom setter and getter methods and will give the same results on console and application.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not calling the `somefield` method at all, that is why it is not being decoded. In your example you are calling `data_row[:somefield]`. You should be calling `model.somefield`.